# Ordering a list of strings and integers on the integers

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have this list with a property (string) which contains Integers and Strings. I want to order the list on integers and skip the strings.

**I had this code:**

```
items = items.OrderBy(Function(b) Convert.ToInt32(b.BranchCode))
```

Except this obviously gives me the error that I am trying to parse a string to integer which is not possible.

Is there a way arround this?

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: What is the error message?  Also, so I'm reading this right, you're saying your list contains `Object` instances?

Comment: `a property which contains Integers and Strings` all the characters must be numerals for it to work, is that the case?

Comment: @Plutonix That's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the return value of Int32.TryParse and, depending on the result (true/false) use the converted value or use the predefined Int32.MaxValue to put the item in the correct position

```
Dim num as Integer
items = items.OrderBy(Function(b) _
        If Int32.TryParse(b.BranchCode, num),  num, Int32.MaxValue )
```